# updating my table is always returning blank while response is successful

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to submit a update request through my form and postman, but I keep getting the same thing in the response

> updated:

Although nothing is changing in my db, the data was full it emptied it the first time and nothing is updating

could it be that the end field is affecting the query ?

```
function update(Request $request, Response $response) {
    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');
    $name = $request->getParam('name'); 
    $start = $request->getParam('start');
    $end = $request->getParam('end');


    $sql = "UPDATE table_timing SET
                name  = :name,
                start  = :start,
                end  = :end

            WHERE table_timing.id = :id";

    try {
        $db = new db();
        $db = $db->connect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
        $stmt->bindParam(':end', $end);


        $stmt->execute();

        $db = null;

        $response->getBody()->write
            ('
            {
                "notice":
                {
                    "status":"200",
                    "message":"Updated"
                }
            }');

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $response->getBody()->write
        ('
        {
            "error":
            {
                "message":'. $e->getMessage() .'
            }
        }');
    }
};
```

Comment: did you try running the sql directly on the sql console?

Comment: @perodriguezl tried it now, i get #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; i'm guessing its because of the reserved words name, start, end but do you think its possible to fix it without having to change all the fields names ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html 
"name", "start" and "end" are all mysql reserved words, you have to change the field name or wrap the field name in '`' (not quotes)

example: `name`

Also for exception, I think it is because your query is made but wrong, it only shows error if query didn't run at all.

Comment: I tried wrapping the field names with '' like this `'end'` but now whenever i use postman i get "error":
            {
                "message":SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''name',
                'start',
                'end'
  ' at line 3

Comment: it is "`" not quotes,  the keyboard button on the left of "!" and "1"

Comment: ok so i tried it like that ` name ` without the spaces but now i get message":SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null

Comment: your issue for this post is solved then. the error message is a new error, it means you are trying to put an NULL value inside a database table field that is not allowing null value. check your table structure. var_dump your $id, $name, $start, $end and see which is null

Comment: trying the command in mysql is returning this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '21:29:06,`end`=2017-06-18 21:29:06 WHERE `id`=1' at line 1

Comment: you only added the syntax error, i can not see your full query and your table structure, i suggest you make new question with your table structure and full query. from the fraction of your error, i think there is a query error on your start value, does the input format match your table field type?

Comment: its not about the null value, i am inserting any null value i am giving it a value.

Comment: First SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null. did you get this message from your code or directly run in mysql ? if you get this from your code , then it means atleast one of your variables are null and your table structure is preventing you from inserting it.

Comment: then how did you get pass that error and get new error of  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: sorry i tried it from postman i get this error, my question is why is it taking the values null where there is values that im passing in the body ?SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null.

Comment: that's what i thought, there is something wrong when you passing the variables from your request,  i can not see your other codes so i can not be sure. but if you var_dump your $id, $name , $start  and $end in your php code inside your update function and then run , you will see their value match your postman or not. this is the first step to make sure the variable is passing correctly to your function.

Comment: moved it to a new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45595479/error-updating-record-in-database